# What's the difference between hdparm APM and spindown?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, hdparm

When I check `hdparm` man page, I see two options which looks similar to reduce power usage by hard drive. One is `-B` which sets APM (Advanced Power Management) and other one is `-S` which is the standby (spindown) timeout for the drive.

What exactly is the difference between these two options?
And I want to decrease power usage, but not wearing out my disk. Which values should I set?